# Populate a dropdown list with filtered data

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-2013

I am trying to find a way to make a dropdown list that only contains items if a condition is met in a different column of the source table.

So basically I have a table with a list of all jobs, past and present. Some have been completed and some are still open. Column A contains the job numbers which are all unique and column P lets the user know if the job is open or closed. If the job is closed the cell contains a "Y", if the job is still open the cell is empty.

I have another table which has a dropdown list which allows the user to select the job they are working on. To keep the size of the dropdown list reasonable I only want it to contain the job numbers of jobs that are still open. Is there a way to use an IF statement or similar to only populate the dropdown list with job numbers from column A if column P is empty?

I've found several examples of using one dropdown list to change the items in a different dropdown list but it seems like they all require the source data to be known and in named ranges beforehand, whereas for me this is going to be a dynamic list as jobs are closed and others are added. So far I've been unable to find anything I can apply to my situation.

Comment: I would look into making a macro that creates an array of Column A, omitting the rows where the jobs are done, and then putting that array into a drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to make the list, is to use a macro to do it.

If you go through the column, and then put every job that isn't closed in an Array,
you can then put the array as the list.

```
Sub makeList()
Dim arr() As Variant, i As Integer, lnght As Long
lnght = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 0
For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lnght)
    If Not cell.Offset(0, 15).Value = "Y" Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i) As Variant
        arr(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

With Range("C1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:=Join(arr, ",")
End With
End Sub
```

This puts the drop down list in "C1", so just change that to where it's supposed to be.

This needs to be updated every time a job is added, removed, or changed to closed.
You could have an update button, or just put the code in the worksheet.
I'd suggest calling it with a `Worksheet_Change`, and if you don't want it to run on every change, add an intersect method to validate if the target of the change is relevant to the list.

Also this assumes the delimiter to be ",", so change that accordingly if needed.